# Sidebar API opr.sidebarAction.setBadgeText doesn't work in Opera 36.0.2114.0

Tags: opera-extension

In extensions on Opera 36.0.X isn't possible show badge over icon on sidebar. Bug is confirmed on 36.0.2114.0 and didn't exist on 34.0.X

Comment: Thank you for notifying about that! It was confirmed and reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in Opera Developer 37.0.2163.0